# Artifact of Spring Boot project generated by IntelliJ IDEA causes errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a Spring Boot project using IntelliJ IDEA and everything works fine. I have no problem running and testing the application inside IntelliJ IDEA. It runs perfectly whether I configure it as an "Application" or "Spring Boot" (from the Run/Edit Configuration menu)

However, problems occur after I created an artifact and try to run it using "java -jar AppName.jar". It spews out errors like:

> Could not find key 'spring.profiles.active' in any property source

and

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.

I extracted the jar file and the spring.factories, etc. files are indeed inside the folder "META-INF".

**I suspect the cause of the problem is the class path. When I run it from within IntelliJ IDEA, I noticed that it is set to module in "Use Classpath of Module". However, in the artifact, I could not get the settings right.**

**What do you think is the cause of the problem? I think it is the class path. If not, what else can it be? Please help!**

I'm providing my pom.xml file here:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.kurento.tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>kurento-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>6.6.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>WebRTCLiveApp</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>WebRTCLiveApp</name>
<description>Company Live App</description>

<licenses>
    <license>
        <name>Apache 2.0</name>
        <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0</url>
        <distribution>repo</distribution>
    </license>
</licenses>

<organization>
    <name>Kurento</name>
    <url>http://www.kurento.org</url>
</organization>

<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>kurento.org</id>
        <name>-kurento.org Community</name>
        <organization>Kurento.org</organization>
        <organizationUrl>http://www.kurento.org</organizationUrl>
    </developer>
</developers>

<properties>

    <!-- Main class -->
    <start-class>com.company.live.webrtc.WebRTCLiveApp</start-class>

</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Kurento -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kurento</groupId>
        <artifactId>kurento-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.kurento</groupId>
        <artifactId>kurento-utils-js</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>draggabilly</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>demo-console</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>adapter.js</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
        <artifactId>ekko-lightbox</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                <layout>ZIP</layout>
                <classifier>exec</classifier>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>banner.txt</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>default</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>no-assembly</id>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

I have search and tried other examples/solutions and none worked.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: The first error seems like an issue not finding a `.properties` file. Where are your `.properties` files located? Are they included in the classpath in the manifest of the JAR?

Comment: You need to use spring boot maven plugin to build executable jar. Spring boot executable jar has a different structure from regular executable jar.

Comment: Don't create the artifiact in initellij... Use manve with the spring boot plugin (which is designed for that). I suggest removing the exec plugin, the assembly plugin and antrun plugin. That is a task of the Spring Boot Plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is resolved.

In the IntelliJ Artifacts Create JAR from Modules dialog box, I have to

1. choose "Copy to output directory and link via manifest" option
2. make sure the META-INF/MANIFEST.INF file is set to "src/main/resources"

Everything is working now (after spending the entire afternoon).

Comment: You are using Spring Boot and as such should also use the Spring Boot Maven Plugin to create an executable artifact. You are working around the framework instead of with the framework.

Comment: Maven is the build tool and make sure you use that. IntelliJ is not a good option as you are not allowing it to be integrated with the CI tools like Jenkins etc. I would recommend to add the spring boot maven plugin and proceed with building with maven, though you already resolved it.

Answer (score -1):

If it is an maven project, it is recommended to add pom.xml

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```